# How to pass nothing to a function using ternary operator - javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-operator

I was wondering if I can do the following with a ternary operator instead of if-else.

```
if (myPath === '/') {
    next({ path: '/articles', query: { page: 1 } });
} else {
    next();
}
```

What I want to do is to replace all of that with just one line:-

```
next(myPath === '/' ? { path: '/articles', query: { page: 1 } } : nothing);
```

If I'm going in the right direction then it just mainly boils down to passing 'nothing' to the `next` function. This is a code sample from the VueJS router navigation guard by the way if it's any help.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: you can pass `null`

Comment: ... or `undefined`, though it will still be counted as an argument. Basically you cannot *really* do what you're asking, but `undefined` is close. It depends on how the function interprets the actual argument list.

Comment: for that you can create function like this: 
`function next(data = null){}` then you can pass anything or nothing.

Comment: Well you can do it, but not with a simple function call. You can use `.apply()` and build an argument array with either nothing in it or something.

Comment: @Pointy, I thought about mentioning `undefined` too but I think `null` is more appropriate as it represents an *explicit* lack of something. Anyway I agree from the practical point of view they are pretty much equivalent, for this use case; it is just a matter of preference.

Comment: Okay, I got it. I tried passing `null` as @secan suggested but it didn't work because VueJS blocked the navigation and gave an error. It interpreted null in some way as @Pointy pointed out. So I passed `true` instead. It worked.

Comment: @secan `undefined` would much more appropriate since they want to emulate `next()` from `else` block. And, if `next` has a [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), it would only be used if undefined is passed

Comment: You should keep your if-else block. It is simple and very readable. The ternary has no upside. It is confusing and makes no difference performance wise

Comment: @adiga This is just a piece of code that is inside an if inside of another if. It was getting confusing so I thought of getting rid of this one block. This code by itself is more readable than the ternary operator though, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply bring the Boolean expression outside of the function call like below:

```
myPath === '/' ? next({ path: '/articles', query: { page: 1 } }) : next();
```

This would be equivalent of your `if-else` code as in case of else as well you're calling `next` method but without any argument.